# Setting the font to .txt file in Java

Tags: java, printing

I have created a .txt file in my code. Now I want to set the Font to the String while writing the .txt file. How can I set the font in .txt file? When I can print that .txt file through Java code it is not in proper font format.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Font in .txt files.

Answer (score 3):

Text files do not have a 'font'.  They are plain text.  For storing a font you'd need a formatted document type like RTF or HTML.

> ..when I can print that .txt file through java code..

Setting a font is done in the printing code, or a text component that the text is rendered in.

Comment: can RTF File is supported to the Linux

Comment: RTF is supported in all desktop OS' as well as by the J2SE.  A `JEditorPane` will render RTF (and HTML).